Why are docker builds on mac apparently trying to use a proxy?
I have the following Dockerfile:
FROM debian:bullseye-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake 

I've installed Docker Desktop on Mac via brew install --cask docker. When I run docker build ., it fails with:
 > [2/2] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake:
0.100 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
0.100   Could not connect to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
0.100 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
0.100   Unable to connect to localhost:8080:
0.100 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
0.100   Unable to connect to localhost:8080:
0.101 Reading package lists...
0.105 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Could not connect to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
0.105 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to localhost:8080:
0.105 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to localhost:8080:
0.105 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

It appears as though it is trying to run through a proxy, but I'm not sure why. env | grep -i proxy is empty.
$ cat ~/.docker/daemon.json
{
 "builder": {
  "gc": {
   "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
   "enabled": true
  }
 },
 "experimental": false
}

A few other bits of info:

The same Dockerfile builds fine on Linux
cargo install or apt get install in a docker build produces a similar issue. Basically anything that hits the network inside a Dockerfile tries to go through localhost:8080
docker pull and other docker network operations outside of build do not have a problem, they don't appear to be using a proxy
I've tried a factory reset and a full uninstall/reinstall of docker desktop

Why might builds be failing in a way that looks like it is trying to use a proxy?

Can you post a complete sample so that others can try?

@Philippe I've changed the example to a different Dockerfile that doesn't require any external context. Is that what you meant by a complete sample?

You might have in "$HOME/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json"
"overrideProxyHttp": "http://localhost:8080",


All of the overrideProxy* settings in ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json are set to ""

Do you have anything setup in Docker Desktop GUI->Resources->Proxies ?

The Manual proxy configuration slider is off in the GUI, and all fields below it are empty.
